# About String and WirteUTF InputStream

Tags: java, sockets

This is part of my programme:

```
boolean bConnected = flase;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;
List<CLient> clients;
public void send(String str) {
try {
           dos.writeUTF(str);
}
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

-----------------------Part 1--------------------------------

while (bConnected=true) {
         System.out.println(dis.readUTF().toString());
         for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
               Client c = clients.get(i);
               c.send(dis.readUTF().toString());}}
------------------Part 2----------------------------------

while (bConnected) {
         String str = dis.readUTF();
         System.out.println(str);
         for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
               Client c = clients.get(i);
               c.send(str);}}
```

This programme is to send the message to other clients.
Only the Second part of Code works. I want to know why i can not use dis.readUTF() directly
I want to know why.

Comment: readUTF() already returns a String. Calling toString() on that is pointless. Your question is meaningless until you tell what happens instead of the first part working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite some difference in behaviour bewtween your code snippets.

```
while (bConnected == true) { /* Note the use of `=` instead of `==` in your question */

    System.out.println(dis.readUTF().toString());           // Reads from the input stream 

    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {

        Client c = clients.get(i);
        c.send(dis.readUTF().toString());                   // Reads from the input stream
    }
}
```

This snippet reads `n + 1` strings from the input stream `dis` per iteration of the outer `while` loop (with `n` being the number of clients in `clients`), whereas your second snippet reads only one string from the input stream per iteration of the `while` loop.

```
while (bConnected) {

    String str = dis.readUTF();                   // Reads from `dis`
    System.out.println(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {

         Client c = clients.get(i);
         c.send(str);                             // uses data read above, doesn't touch `dis`
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks, i think i got it